# Some problems using bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

My layout page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/toaster.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/toaster.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-app="plyaerManagement">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href='#/Play/Home'>Request Data</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#/Play/Log'>Show Logs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/app/app.js")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="~/app/Resource.js"></script>
    <script src="~/app/Sensor/SensorController.js"></script>
    <script src="~/app/Log/SensorLogController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here how it looks like:

[image]

When I make it smaller I get this:

[image]

The problem is when I press the menu button in right upper corner the dropbox have to display options:

**Request Data**

**Show Logs**

But in my case when I press the menu in right upper corner the dropbox not 
open and I don't see any options.

Do you have any idea why the menu button not working in my case?

Comment: Check to see if the Bootstrap and jQuery JavaScript files are being included.

Comment: Try to use an ID reference in the (data-target) instead of a CSS reference

Comment: @Ala,what do you mean by  ID reference in the (data-target)?

Comment: I mean, add an id="test" to the div you want to collapse, and in the collapsing button, set data-target="#test"